# Selecting the Parent Menu

Tags: css, menu, dropdown, parent, submenu

when I select the submenu in the parent menu in [this link](http://www.kilavuzcepte.com), I made the background of the top menu red.

But the color of the text becomes black, I cannot make it white.

Thank you for your help in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give also the `a tag` a color while you hover on the li, try the one below:

```css
.header .dropdown-submenu > li:hover > a, .header .dropdown > ul > li:hover > a {
    color: #fff;
}
```